Recovering the classical Navier-Stokes equation from Landau's relativistic tensor
I'm trying to get to the classical compressible Navier-Stokes equation from the relativistic tensors in the Landau/Eckart frame. I understand these have their own problems about entropy.
In several sources, including:

Landau and Lifshitz Volume 6
Weinberg Gravitation Part 1 chapter 11
this answer here

and various others, they all derive the shear part of the stress-energy tensor to have preceding minus signs.
$$
\tau_{\mu\nu} = -\eta \left[\partial_\mu u_\nu+\partial_\nu u_\mu - u_\mu u^\sigma \partial_\sigma u_\nu - u_\nu u^\sigma\partial_\sigma u_\mu\right] - \lambda\partial_\sigma u^\sigma(g_{\mu\nu}-u_\mu u_\nu)
$$
Where I have replaced the bulk viscosity coefficient with $\lambda = \zeta - \frac{2}{3}\eta$. Weinberg says this is to have a positive "rate of entropy product per unit volume at P" (From page 55 where the formula is for $\frac{\partial S^\alpha}{\partial x^\alpha}$). I'm happy so far.
My question is how does this match back onto the classical Navier-Stokes equation? I seem to get a different sign and I can't understand why. I'll use downstairs indices on the stress-energy tensor to be consistent with the sources and remove the pressure term for simplicity.
\begin{equation}
T_{\mu\nu} = w v_\mu v_\nu - \lambda \left(g_{\mu\nu} - v_\mu v_\nu \right)\partial_\sigma v^\sigma - \eta\left(\partial_\mu v_\nu + \partial_\nu v_\mu - v_\mu v^\sigma \partial_\sigma v_\nu - v_\nu v^\sigma\partial_\sigma v_\mu \right).
\end{equation}
Using $\partial^\mu T_{\mu\nu} = 0$ and dropping terms cubic in $v$ (suppressed by $\frac{1}{c^2}$) we get
$$  -w v_\mu \partial^\mu v_\nu = w v_\nu\partial^\mu v_\mu - \lambda\partial_\nu \partial_\sigma v^\sigma  - \eta \partial^\mu \partial_\mu v_\nu - \eta\partial_\nu\partial^\mu v_\mu.$$
Now setting $\nu=j$ to get the spatial components ($v_\nu \to -\mathbf v$), and using a non-relativistic limit so that
$$v^\mu \partial_\mu \approx \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \mathbf v \cdot \nabla \quad \text{and} \quad \partial_\mu v^\mu \approx \nabla \cdot v \quad \text{and} \quad \partial_\mu \partial^\mu = \square \approx -\nabla^2 .$$
We get to
$$ w \frac{\partial \mathbf v}{\partial t} + w (\mathbf v \cdot \nabla) \mathbf v = -w \mathbf v (\nabla \cdot \mathbf v) - \eta\nabla^2 \mathbf v - (\eta + \lambda)\nabla (\nabla \cdot \mathbf v).$$
This so nearly looks like the compressible Navier-Stokes except the $\eta$ and $\lambda$ have a negative sign. But Weinberg insists that the negative is required. What's gone wrong in my working?

Be aware that the sign convention of Landau may be different than the sign convention used by Weinberg and others.  Seek for example the Minkwoski metric: $\eta = \text{diag}(1, -1, -1, -1)$ (Landau's convention) and $\eta = \text{diag}(-1, 1, 1, 1)$ (Weinberg's convention).
